# c++ I need to read data from a file into a multi-dimensional array then sort the array with one data type. How?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort the net pays of employees as part of a payroll program. Employees are identified by an id number followed by their net pay. Like this:

```
11111 456.78
22222 891.01
33333 112.13
```

I need to sort the data so that it looks like this

```
22222 891.01
11111 456.78
33333 112.13
```

So basically I  need to sort them by their pay but I need the id number to match the sorted pay.

code i have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

/* Read data from file into array*/
int readData(long int[], double[], int);

/*print data from array unsorted*/
void printUnsorted(long int[], double, int);

/* sort items from array*/
void sort(long int[], double[], int);

/*Display sorted data to console*/
void printSorted(long int[], double, int);

void main() {

    const int MAXSIZE = 100;

    int n;
    long int id[MAXSIZE];
    double netpay[MAXSIZE];

    n = readData(id, netpay, MAXSIZE);
    printUnsorted(id, netpay);
    sort(id, netpay);
    printSorted(id, netpay);
}

int readData(long int id[], double netpay[], int n) {
    ifstream input;
    input.open("netpay.txt");
    n = 0;

    while (input >> id[n] >> netpay[n]) n++;

    input.close();
    return n;
}

void printUnsorted(long int id[], double netpay[], int n) {
    cout << "Unsorted Data" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << id[i] << "\t" << netpay[i] << "\t" << endl;
    }


void sort(long int id[], double netpay[], int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sort(netpay.begin(), netpay.end()); 
    }   
}

void printSorted(long int id[], double netpay[], int n) {
    cout << "Sorted Data" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << id[i] << "\t" << netpay[i] << "\t" << endl;
    }   
}
```

Very messy I know, can anyone give me a step in the right direction? After this I have to do the same thing with pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The are lots of thing to improve in your code. You have several syntax errors too. I recommend trying to debug you code first. But, the sorting part can be done as follows. First, make pairs from the data (id, netpay). Then, save pairs in a container like `std::vector.` Next, sort the pairs using `std::sort` with respect to their second elements, netpays. Finally, write back the data from pairs into `id` and `netpay` arrays.

```
void my_sort(int id[], double netpay[], int n) {
    typedef std::pair<int, double> data_pair_t;
    std::vector<data_pair_t> data;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        data.push_back(make_pair(id[i], netpay[i]));
    }

    sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](data_pair_t a, data_pair_t b) {
        return a.second < b.second;
        } );  

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        id[i] = data[i].first;
        netpay[i] = data[i].second;
    }
}
```

You may check the code [here](http://ideone.com/u3NVGa) and extend it as you progress. Of course, things can be simplified if you use `std::vector` instead of arrays and particular data structure for your input data.

Comment: thank your for your timely response! Ill mess around with your code example. I really really wish I could use vectors for this assignment unfortunately we are not allowed. All the same, this was a big help thanks!